# Adding AutoFilter Criteria one by one

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to add AutoFilter Criteria to my excel table in separate Subs.

What I have at the moment looks a little something like this

```
.AutoFilter Field:=deviceTypeColumnId, Criteria1:=[dScenarioIndependent], Operator:=xlOr, _
                                       Criteria2:=[dSmartphoneDeviceType]
```

What I would like to have is a method to first filter by Criteria1, and then, in another Sub, add Criteria2 to the existing AutoFilter. To my mind, it should look something like this:

```
Sub firstSub
    .AutoFilter Field:=deviceTypeColumnId, Criteria1:=[dScenarioIndependent]
end sub
Sub secondSub
    .AutoFilter mode:=xlAddCriteria, Field:=deviceTypeColumnId, Criteria1:=[dSmartphoneDeviceType]        
    'I know that mode doesn't exist, but is there anything like that?
end sub
```

Do you know any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, that I know of, a way of "adding on" criteria to a filter which has previously been applied.

I have produced a work-around, which would work for what you are attempting to do. You will just have to add on scenarios to the select case statement, going up to the maximum number of filters which you will want to have.

EDIT: what it does; copy the filtered column to a new worksheet, and remove duplicates on that column. You're then left with the values which have been used to filter the column. Assign the values to an array, and then apply the number of elements of the array as a filter on the column, whilst including the new value you wish to filter on.
EDIT 2: added in a function to find the last row for when a table is already filtered (we want the last row, not the last visible row).

```
Option Explicit
Sub add_filter()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, new_ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrCriteria() As Variant, strCriteria As String
    Dim num_elements As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long, new_lrow As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("data")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("A1:A" & lrow).Copy 'Copy column which you intend to add a filter to
    Sheets.Add().Name = "filter_data"
    Set new_ws = wb.Sheets("filter_data")

    With new_ws
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("$A$1:$A$" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes   'Shows what has been added to filter
        new_lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If new_lrow = 2 Then
            strCriteria = .Range("A2").Value 'If only 1 element then assign to string
        Else
            arrCriteria = .Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'If more than 1 element make array
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    If new_lrow = 2 Then
        num_elements = 1
    Else
        num_elements = UBound(arrCriteria, 1) 'Establish number elements in array
    End If

    lrow = last_row
    Select Case num_elements
        Case 1
            ws.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lrow).AutoFilter 1, _
            Array(strCriteria, "New Filter Value"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Case 2
            ws.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lrow).AutoFilter 1, _
            Array(arrCriteria(1, 1), arrCriteria(2, 1), _
            "New Filter Value"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Case 3
            ws.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lrow).AutoFilter 1, _
            Array(arrCriteria(1, 1), arrCriteria(2, 1), _
            arrCriteria(3, 1), "New Filter Value"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Function:

```
Function last_row() As Long
    Dim rCol As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set rCol = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("A"))
    lRow = rCol.Row + rCol.Rows.Count - 1
    Do While Len(Range("A" & lRow).Value) = 0
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    last_row = lRow
End Function
```

Hope this helps.