# Combine criteria / macros VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, logical-operators, multiple-conditions

```
Sub Macro_1()
Dim RowIndex, x As Integer
Dim RowArr() As String
RowIndex = "8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17"
RowArr = Split(RowIndex, ",")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheets("Test").Select
  
  For x = 0 To UBound(RowArr)
    ActiveSheet.Rows().AutoFilter Field:=CInt(RowArr(x))
  Next
  ActiveSheet.Rows().AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
  Sheets("Test").Select
  Call SetClassFields("1")
  Call Macro_Filter
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub Macro_2()
Dim RowIndex, x As Integer
Dim RowArr() As String
RowIndex = "8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17"
RowArr = Split(RowIndex, ",")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheets("Test").Select
  
  For x = 0 To UBound(RowArr)
    ActiveSheet.Rows().AutoFilter Field:=CInt(RowArr(x))
  Next
  ActiveSheet.Rows().AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
  Sheets("Test").Select
  Call SetClassFields("2")
  Call Macro_Filter
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have a table with several criteria. Until now, only one criterion had to be filtered at a time. Now several columns that contain the X should be filtered. Now I'm thinking of how to combine these two macros.

Comment: Have you looked at [this reference](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/#Example-Multiple-Criteria-ANDOR-in-the-Same-Column) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31157764/4717755)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, even if you're a beginner, you should know what YOUR code does. It seems you put things, not really knowing what they do. For example, the following does absolutely nothing.

```
For x = 0 To UBound(RowArr)
  ActiveSheet.Rows().AutoFilter Field:=CInt(RowArr(x))
Next
```

It can be safely removed.

It means `x`, `RowIndex` and `RowArr` can also be removed, because you don't use them elsewhere.

Also, there is no need to use `.Select`, as any sheet or range can be referenced without actually selecting it. In your code we can see `Sheets("Test").Select` two times. The second one does absolutely nothing. The first one is advised to be removed. When you remove, in the following line instead of `ActiveSheet` you can use `Sheets("Test")` which is the same reference, but without unnecessary `Sheets("Test").Select`.

Your fixed macros may look like this:

```
Sub Macro_1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
  Call SetClassFields("1")
  Call Macro_Filter
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Macro_2()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
  Call SetClassFields("2")
  Call Macro_Filter
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope I'm correct, because you may have shortened your code for example purposes...

Now, to your question. I assume you run your scripts one after another. So the main code parts may just be put inside one script like this:

```
Sub Macro_3()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
  Call SetClassFields("1")
  Call Macro_Filter
  Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
  Call SetClassFields("2")
  Call Macro_Filter
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

If you want to be able to choose which path to go (OR condition), you need to give a parameter to the function (let's call the parameter `i`).

```
Sub caller()
  Call Macro_x(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Macro_x(i As Integer)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  If i = 1 Then
    Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
  ElseIf i = 2 Then
    Sheets("Test").Rows().AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>"
  Else
    MsgBox "parameter i was not defined"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Call SetClassFields(CStr(i))
  Call Macro_Filter
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In this code you see the main function (`caller`) and another (`Marcro_x`), which is called inside `caller`. You must provide a parameter in parentheses when you call `Macro_x` - `1` or `2`. Depending on the parameter provided, the sub will do slightly different things.

Comment: I updated the answer with how I imagine OR should be implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much